# Is it possible to reverse engineer out the loss based on weights update when data is unknown?

Tags: backpropagation

Assume the gradient updates (both $W_t$ and $W_{t+1}$) and learning rate are known while data $X$ is unknown, is it possible to deduce the loss $L$ used in backprop algorithm that gave rise to the gradient update $W_{t+1} - W_{t}$? If not, is it possible to verify if a given loss is the one we are looking for (in other words is the loss that gave rise to a known gradient update unique, assume we know the model architecture)?

Comment: This depends on your definition of Loss $L$, $L$ such as MSE is easily calculable according to its formula after each forward pass and its error terms for each output unit are then used to backprop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no way you could recover the exact loss. At best you could recover the loss up to a constant factor, because the gradient is only giving information on the slope on the loss and not the actual loss values.

If we make assumptions like a standard model architecture, and we have access to the model architecture in addition to the weight values, then it *might* be possible to recover the loss up to a constant factor. Assuming the (scalar) loss depends only on the output layer, and assuming the weights are updated with vanilla SGD, first we have an eqn like
\begin{align*} 
\frac{1}{\alpha}(W_{t+1} - W_t) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\Big(\dfrac{\partial x_n}{\partial W_t} + \dfrac{\partial x_n}{\partial x_{n-1}}\dfrac{\partial x_{n-1}}{\partial W_t} + \ldots \Big)
\end{align*}
where $\alpha$ is the learning rate, $f$ is the loss function, $x_i$ are the units of the $i$-th layer ($x_n$ is output, $x_0$ is input). the LHS is what you know the gradient was and the RHS is the definition of the gradient (based on backprop). In the RHS, the unknowns are the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$, which has as many unknowns as dimension of the output layer. This is an over-determined system, because there are only $\text{dim}(x_n)$ unknowns and $\dim(W)$ equations. Normally this would then have no solution, but in this case, we know there actually are some loss partial derivatives $\partial f / \partial x_n$ which should satisfy this.

But this doesn't give you the actual function f. You just get the partial derivatives at $x_n$. Then if you wanted to try to recover $f$ (again, only up to a constant factor), you would need a way to actually evaluate various different $x_n$. Then you can "recover" $f$ (up to a constant factor) by integrating $\partial f / \partial x_n$ over all possible values of $x_n$.